# Is it better to replace an image src with JS, or to use CSS filters to manipulate it?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, frontend

I have a button with an icon, whose source is an SVG of ~4kb. When I hover over the button, I want the icon to invert in color, changing from black to white. To achieve this effect, is it better to use CSS like so:

```
#btn:hover #icon-img {
    -webkit-filter: invert(1);
    filter: invert(1); 
}
```

...or is it better (e.g. faster/best practice/better for memory) to manipulate the image source directly and add a white version of the icon like so?

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    document.getElementById('icon-img').src = 'white-image.svg';
}
```

Comment: I think I even better way would be to change the `fill` color if you're already using an SVG... you just have to make sure your SVGs are inlined, not using `<img>` tags.

Comment: Thanks! I have a lot of SVGs, so I think inlining all the SVGs is a little too maintenance-intensive... but it's a good idea!

Comment: It's not too terrible if you use a templating engine or script to do it for you. Just give it a filename and it'll do all the work.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, CSS solutions are a better approach that JS-based ones.

The main problem with CSS (specially regarding new fancy features) is support:

[Browser support for filter property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility)

As you can see, you are out of luck if you want to support IE (althought Internet Explorer 4.0 to 9.0 implemented a non-standard and deprecated filter property).

As @guest271314 has pointed out, your JS solution will trigger a new request to the server... you could consider using sprites or data URIs to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `css` to not make additional network request for image at each `mouseover` event.